# Problem with getting data in continuous loop

Tags: c#, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to get data from database continuously after clicking a button, but it does not work. The pin is supposed to appear at given coordinates from database but instead it just stands still at the neutral point. [neutral location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQtmA.png)

I've used the same approach to save the data and it works perfectly fine in a loop.

Getting the data:

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), () =>
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {

                var response = await mapsRepo.GetPartnerLocation("tDwV0laF9ueBre8jHwxw6EsnCry1");

                double lattitude = Convert.ToDouble(response[0].lat);
                double longitude = Convert.ToDouble(response[0].lng);

                pin.Position = new Position(lattitude, longitude);

               

            });
            return true;
        });
```

The problem seems to be with a loop itself, while i remove it and leave only firebase request, the data is taken correctly but not in the continuous loop of course
Expected pin behavior is to track the person, which it does perfectly fine without the loop [expected pin behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaOHV.png) [expected pin behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVpu0.png)

Maps package:

> xamarin.forms.maps\5.0.0.2515\

Comment: "does not work" is not a useful description of the problem.  Are you getting an error or exception?  What **specifically** is it doing (or not doing)?  What debugging steps have you taken?

Comment: This will return `true` before the Task has had a chance to finish. Is that intended behavior?

Comment: no, not intended, can u explain where is the mistake?

Comment: You have to `await` asynchronous tasks if you want them to finish before continuing to execute code that comes after.

Comment: I think in Xamarin you can't update the UI from a different thread other than the UI thread, so when you run the code in the `Task.Run` you start a new thread, ask to update the UI, and crash that thread instead of updating the UI. You'd need to remove the Task.Run, but `Device.StartTimer` does not accept async functions so you would have to write your own `Device.StartTimerAsync`